# apex:selectList component readonly property is not working

Tags: visualforce

I am using `apex:selectList` component and trying to make it `readonly` by setting its `readonly` property like below -

```
<apex:selectList value="{!state}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="state" readonly="true">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!stateOptions}"/> 
</apex:selectList>
```

I am setting its value using one javascript function dynamically something like below -

```
document.getElementById('j_id0:frm:j_id10:j_id21:pbtCostDetails:state').value = 'Jaipur';
```

problem is it is not getting readonly. User is able to select any value in select list.

Thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly it's nothing wrong with Visualforce, it's the `<select>` HTML tag that's bit quirky to use. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191113/disable-select-form-field-but-still-send-the-value or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/readonly-select-tag, inspect the generated HTML in the browser...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some difference between `readonly` and `disabled` parameters.

If you want to show the picklist visually as disabled on the page you need to use `disabled="true"` parameter.

If you want, that selected value will not transmitted to the controller you need to use `readonly="true"`.

Here is a test page. Just testing it.

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" title="Selection" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit"/>
        Selected Value:<apex:outputText value="{!output}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false" collapsible="false">
        <apex:outputLabel value="Select:" for="state"/>    
        <apex:selectList value="{!output}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="state" readonly="true">
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2"/>
        </apex:selectList>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

**1) Readonly = true**
After submition the value from the picklist is not transferred to the controller.
[image]

**2) Readonly = false**
The value successfuly transferred.
[image]

**2) Disabled = true**
The picklist is completely disabled.

[image]

Comment: As per your reply, in both the cases "disabled" and "readonly" values don't submit to controller. but i read somewhere that in case of "disabled" value doesn't get transferred to controller but in case of "Readonly" values get transferred to controller. Can you please confirm?

Comment: It is not directly documented (is it?). The documentation says: `If set to true (readonly), the list option selections cannot be changed.` I've tried it on my dev org and if readonly is set to true then i cannot get the selected value in controller.

Comment: I am not sure about the salesforce specifically. but html code work like this. "ReadOnly" gets submitted to server but "Disabled" doesn't. I am not sure then where should i use "Readonly=true" property.

Comment: @PramodKumar I think just use `disabled` and you are on the right way.